# Почему при удалении класса таблицы и смены его на id, к ячейкам не применяется hover?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.levels {
  visibility: visible;
  border-spacing: 50px;
  height: 105%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
.levels td {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 5em;
  width: 20%;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: 50% #fff;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.levels td:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(1.3);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}
.play:hover {
  background: url(http://rounverse-nulh.c9users.io/img/play.svg) no-repeat 50% #50a050;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
}
.lock:hover {
  background: url(http://rounverse-nulh.c9users.io/img/lock.svg) no-repeat 50% #f05050;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<table class="levels">
  <tr>
    <td class='play'>1</td>
    <td class='play'>2</td>
    <td class='play'>3</td>
    <td class='play'>4</td>
    <td class='play'>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='lock'>6</td>
    <td class='lock'>7</td>
    <td class='lock'>8</td>
    <td class='lock'>9</td>
    <td class='lock'>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='play'>11</td>
    <td class='play'>12</td>
    <td class='play'>13</td>
    <td class='play'>14</td>
    <td class='play'>15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='play'>16</td>
    <td class='play'>17</td>
    <td class='play'>18</td>
    <td class='play'>19</td>
    <td class='play'>20</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Здесь все работает. Но если в стилях заменить класс таблицы `levels` на id с этим названием,то к ячейкам класса `lock` и `play` hover применяться не будет. Почему? Можно ли обойтись без `!important`?

Фидлл с тем, что я хочу сделать: https://jsfiddle.net/r1xxut8t/

Comment: Не понятно, что именно вы меняете. Убрали классы из хмтл и не добавили новое правило css для id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приоритет у класса и у айди разный: селектор по `id` весомее, чем по `class`.

Почитайте вот тут: [Специфичность](http://htmlbook.ru/samcss/kaskadirovanie)

Чтобы обойтись без `!important`, делайте более полный селектор:

```
#levels td:hover { ... }
#levels td.play:hover { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#levels td.play:hover {
  background: url(http://rounverse-nulh.c9users.io/img/play.svg) no-repeat 50% #50a050;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
}
#levels td.lock:hover {
  background: url(http://rounverse-nulh.c9users.io/img/lock.svg) no-repeat 50% #f05050;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
}
```